# Programmatically extract column descriptions from Informix

Tags: informix

Is there a system table where Informix database stores column descriptions?
I know how to do it in SQL Server, Oracle, but not in Informix...

Comment: What do you mean by "column descriptions"?  There's `"informix".syscolumns` that contains most of what the system knows about columns.  There is no place in the Informix system catalog for storing "this column contains the colour of the Thingamajig" or other such plain text descriptions of the column contents.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's exactly what I've been searching for. I needed to find columns' text descriptions. Strange that there is no such catalog in Informix such catalog as `syscomments` in Oracle e.g.

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to obtain information regarding Informix database objects (like tables or columns) using the Informix catalog tables.
You can get the info directly from the catalog using some basic SQL select statement, for example:

```
SELECT TRIM(c.colname) colname,
CASE
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=0 THEN 'CHAR'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=1 THEN 'SMALLINT'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=2 THEN 'INTEGER'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=3 THEN 'FLOAT'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=4 THEN 'SMALLFLOAT'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=5 THEN 'DECIMAL'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=6 THEN 'SERIAL'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=7 THEN 'DATE'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=8 THEN 'MONEY'
  -- needs more entries --
  ELSE TO_CHAR(coltype)
END AS Type,
BITAND(coltype,256)=256 AS NotNull
  FROM systables  AS t
  JOIN syscolumns AS c ON t.tabid = c.tabid
 WHERE t.tabtype = 'T'   
   AND t.tabname = 'customer'
 ORDER by c.colno;
```

Note that the CASE section will need an entry for each Informix data type.

Description of all catalog tables can be found at:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=reference-system-catalog-tables

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=tables-systables
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=tables-syscolumns

Another method will be to use the INFO SQL statement as described here:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-info-statement

Something like:

```
informix@DESKTOP:~/IDS$ dbaccess stores7 -

Database selected.

> info columns for customer;


Column name          Type                                    Nulls

customer_num         serial                                  no
fname                char(15)                                yes
lname                char(15)                                yes
company              char(20)                                yes
address1             char(20)                                yes
address2             char(20)                                yes
city                 char(15)                                yes
state                char(2)                                 yes
zipcode              char(5)                                 yes
phone                char(18)                                yes
>
```

Alternatively, you can use any metadata method provided by the API (like JDBC's DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've been searching for plain text descriptions though, e.g. like in `syscomments` catalog from Oracle. According to my researches, it is possible to give a column a text description in Informix, similarly to `COMMENT ON` SQL-command. But to retrieve it from catalog, it seems to be impossible

Comment: @HardRock4Life: Can you give us a link to where you found information about text descriptions for columns in Informix databases?  Or a Google search term?

Comment: I don't think Informix supports that. Can't recall any way to add descriptions to table columns.